# the edge of a Button still has a light grey line around it while the edge of it has the same color of background

Tags: android, gradient

I set a Gradient for a Button with Color Red and edge Color of Red too,
The Button is placed inside a Linear Layout with Red color too

The problem is the edge of the Button **still has a light grey line around it**
Why?
Since the edge is Red there should be no edge seen

As is seen in the image, when edge is green still a grey thing is seen

[image]

Comment: check if it is shadow of button.

Comment: Post the layout and a screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default shadow of button in material design guidelines. To remove it put this attribute in your `<Button` element:

```
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Or, programmatically, you can do it in this way:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //Check if it's supported
    yourButton.setStateListAnimator(null);
}
```

Comment: It's a dynamic Button,I need to problematically do that

Comment: Ok, it's true the grey edge disappeared, what about below LOLLIPOP?

Comment: Below Lollipop Buttons don't have default stateListAnimator, so there shouldn't be any problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this code to your button's xml

`style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`